# PHP & MySQL looping problem

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to loop once with the `$cat_id` to grab its `id` and `category` values for the `$url` value and then add the `id` and `category` values to the `$parent_cat_id` and `$sub_cat_name` arrays and then loop the `$parent_cat_id` value just added to the array to find its `id` and `category` values and add them to the arrays until all the `$url` values have been looped. But I can only get the first `$url` value to loop and not the rest of the `$url` values to loop can someone help me correct this problem?

PHP code.

```
$parent_cat_id = array();
$sub_cat_name = array();
$cat_id = 23;

for ($i = 1; isset($_GET['sub'.$i]); ++$i) {
    $url[$i] = '&#038;sub' . $i . '=' . $_GET['sub'.$i];
    if(isset($cat_id)){
        $dbc = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id, category FROM categories WHERE url = '" . $url[$i] . "' AND parent_id = '" . $cat_id . "'");
        if (!$dbc) {
            print mysqli_error($mysqli);
        }  else {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($dbc)){ 
                $parent_cat_id[] = $row['id'];
                $sub_cat_name[] = $row['category'];
            }
        }   
    } else {
        $dbc = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT id, category FROM categories WHERE url = '" . $url[$i] . "' AND parent_id = '" . $parent_cat_id[$i] . "'");
        if (!$dbc) {
            print mysqli_error($mysqli);
        }  else {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($dbc)){ 
                $parent_cat_id[] = $row['id'];
                $sub_cat_name[] = $row['category'];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Current output.

```
$parent_cat_id Array ( [0] => 77 )

$sub_cat_name Array ( [0] => A1 )
```

Expected Output.

```
$parent_cat_id Array ( [0] => 77 [1] => 78 [2] => 97 [3] => 100 )

$sub_cat_name Array ( [0] => A1 [1] => A2 [2] => B4 [3] => CD )
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with `i < PHP_INT_MAX`? I don't think it's good practice to loop i from 1 to `PHP_INT_MAX`. Edit: Perhaps you should remove `$i < PHP_INT_MAX` - I don't think it's necessary.

Comment: since I don't no how many sub categories there are `PHP_INT_MAX` only loops as many times there sub categories so its prefect.

Comment: Also, can you edit this code such that it is as simple as possible while still exhibiting the problems you're experiencing? I don't think any of that database stuff is relevant to your problem.

Comment: Try to comment your code to make it more understandable.

Comment: @Cam how is the database stuff not relevant in the code its part of the question but if you dont think its relevant what stuff should I remove be specific as possible.

Comment: @g4tv (g4tv's first comment): Right, but the loop will stop once there are no more sub categories regardless of the PHP_INT_MAX check. My argument is that the PHP_INT_MAX check is redundant because it does not affect functionality at all (except in an almost-impossible case where GET has that many subs in it - you really don't need to check for that).

Comment: @g4tv (g4tv's second comment): If I understand your question and the code correctly you should remove the entire `if(isset($cat_id)){` part. Also a sample `print_r` of $_GET and $url might help us figure out the problem

Comment: @Cam I `$i < PHP_INT_MAX` removed still worked thanks for the improvement :)

Comment: @Omar Dolaimy what part of the code would you like me to comment be specific as possible thanks.

Comment: @g4tv: No problem. You can then also remove the `$i &&` part.

Comment: @Cam thanks for improving part of my code but this still dosen't fix my main problem :(

Comment: @g4tv: please see my answer below. Perhaps using my answer as a starting point we can pinpoint your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, you're basically saying that the loop runs only once but you want it to run multiple times.

However, check out the code below (simplified from yours). For clarity I've removed most of the loop's contents so you can see what's actually happening...

```
<?php
    $_GET=array('sub1'=>'val_sub1','sub2'=>'val_sub2','sub3'=>'val_sub3','sub4'=>'val_sub4');
    print_r($_GET);
    /*
    Array
    (
        [sub1] => val_sub1
        [sub2] => val_sub2
        [sub3] => val_sub3
        [sub4] => val_sub4
    )
    */

    $url=array();

    for ($i = 1;isset($_GET['sub'.$i]); $i++) {
        $url[$i] = '&#038;sub' . $i . '=' . $_GET['sub'.$i];
    }

    print_r($url);
    /*
    Array
    (
        [1] => &#038;sub1=val_sub1
        [2] => &#038;sub2=val_sub2
        [3] => &#038;sub3=val_sub3
        [4] => &#038;sub4=val_sub4
    )
    */
?>
```

As you can see, the loop works fine. So either...

1. the problem you're experiencing is because something's going horribly wrong with the database stuff and your script is just crashing after one loop (unlikely), or
2. **the $_GET parameter only has one 'sub' value so it actually should just be looping once (likely)**, or
3. Maybe I just don't understand your question as well as I think I do.

Comment: I'm trying to grab the parent_id from each $url

Comment: @g4tv: Okay - how about this: Can you present us with some kind of output (a print_r, for example)? We need: **actual output** (what's actually printed) and **expected output** (what would be printed if the script were to work how you want it to).

Comment: @g4tv: Ah. Well are you sure you have the correct rows in your database? Your code looks fine as far as i can see.

Comment: yeah database is correct I think its my if statements how would I check if `$cat_id` already looped through the database if so loop `$parent_cat_id` through the database?